# Why refer to cocaine as "she"?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

In Cocaine song, by Clapton, why does he refer to cocaine as "she" instead of "it"?

**She don't lie, she don't lie, she don't lie,
Cocaine**

In the same sentence, why does he use "don't" instead of "doesn't"?

Comment: I think most narcotics are identified with women. Coke can be called "girl", "white lady"...

Comment: @jinawee: I don't think Anglophones in general are much into the m/f distinction made in many other languages. But it is worth noting that we usually get our illicit drugs from *"The **man**"*.

Comment: Also (although possibly not the reason Clapton uses it that way) cocaine is a feminine name in most romance language (definitely in Italian, French, Spanish, Portuguese, and possibly in others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*She* personifies the cocaine.

*Don't* as used here is an informal slang usage.

In any case, artistic license lets you write what you want. Also words have to fit the music timing, etc.

Comment: Also, purely as conjecture, I would say Clapton personified cocaine as a female because he was likening it to a relationship, e.g. "If you wanna hang out, you've got to take *her* out". It's a common device, there are many uses of "she" that I don't personally know enough about to give reasons for, but for example: "She" as referring to a car, "Lady luck", referring to things that have control over you as your "mistress", etc.

Comment: @iStimple I would if I had more concrete knowledge of the historical usage of the female gender for such things. I just know it happens, I don't know why.

Answer (score 6):

The use of *she* personifies the drug. Not only that, the word compares the addiction to a damaging love relationship. Cocaine is the temptress that lures you back with *her* love, and that love, like the drug, can hurt you when you break up.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***(she) cocaine*** here is influenced by ***(she) heroine***. While "heroin" is a drug, "[heroine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heroine)" is a female form of "hero", as in "Marie Curie was the tragic heroine of science".

And "she don't" is just clumsiness dressed up as licentia poetica :)

These are just guesses. Why an artist said or sung this or that? Of course nobody exactly knows (including perhaps artist himself).